# May I use zend framework together with php files not using it

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am now working in a team to build a website using php. Told that Zend framework can be fairly convenient, I hope to use it to write the pages. However, some of the members in the team did not use the framework in their previous works. I do not know whether there will be any possible problems if their works are used together with mine? So I wonder whether it is possible for us to use Zend frameworks for part of the website while other members of the team do not use this framework to build the rest of the website? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Of course it's possible.... But I would leave old projects written as they are.... and use Zend for new projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Richard. Then it seems that using Zend for my pages will be acceptable. Only part of these project is done and we just start our work. So maybe it is possible for me to persuade others into using Zend Framework, but I had to make sure that it is possible to use Zend if we fail reach a consensus. And thanking for your advice of using Zend for new projects, which will turn out to be helpful in the future when I am to work on other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i not really sure to undersand your question

but it's look complicated to use ZF for a part of the site, and PHP for the other. However, it's possible. You can, with a .htaccess say that an URL is not define by ZF (i ever used it for a blog attached on a ZF site)

Don't hesitate to comment for any other answer

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not expressing my question clearly. And what I want to do is to use ZF for a part of the site and PHP for the other, just as you said. And I wonder if my page is accessible if my page is writen using Zend Framework while others do not use this framework? Will there be some errors just as you mentioned?

Comment: i can't really understand why you want build a solution like that.
ZF is PHP, so your mate can code inside ZF if they know PHP

For answer your question, with a good .htaccess, it work. But it look really ugly ?!

Comment: Sorry for not expressing every details well. Personally, I hope to use Zend Framework for the whole project, just as you said. But I did not know the framework before, nor did my mates. So I would have to persuade them into using this framework and modifying their code. If it is possible to use the mixture of ZF and PHP without ZF, it will be possible for some of them not to modify their works and I will be able to talk with them more smoothly. Were I to finish the project on my own, things would be easier. But I have to take many other things into consideration as an inexperienced team leader

Comment: All depend on the distribution of work, but i think you will be passed more time to debug for integrate the mixte thank integrate it in ZF. It's my own point of view. After all, i haven't see the project so it's hard to tell you the good solution.

Comment: Thanks you for your advice. So I will first try to pursuade others into using Zend Framework, and there is no need worrying if everyone agrees to use it. And if it is too difficult for mix the code, it is also possible for us not to use Zend Framework at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are splitting up the work. Zend Framework is modular so you are not tied into using the whole framework. You can just select the components you need. I would advise that you use one framework for your application startup and routing at least. Merging these part would be a hassle to maintain imo.

Comment: I want to split up the work according to the functions of each module of the website, and my job is one of these modules. So it is possible for me to use some components in the website to finish my module? I will try to persuade other members into taking your advice and use one framework for startup and routing. Thanks a lot.